# do something with script output

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm lazy :) so I would like to automate some things on my network. Currently I'm running a script that automatically downloads the series I watch every week. Based on what is downloaded another script searches the web for subtitles. Some downloads however have subtitles with them, so searching for subtitles is not necessary. I would like to check every download for subtitles and get notified (or better move the file) if the file has the correct subtitles.

I started with the following:

```
find /volume2/Downloads/ -type f -mmin -30 | while IFS= read -r file; do
    ffmpeg -i "${file}"
done
```

This works and shows me the output of the ffmpeg command for each file newer than 30 minutes. I would like to work with the result given by ffmpeg so that when certain characters are present in the output, I'm notified via mail. My Linux scripting skills however stop at the script I got. I'm a web developer so I understand the logic behind a script like this, but not the specific code or commands.

Characters that I'm looking for:

- (eng): Subtitle:
- (dut): Subtitle:

Can this be done?

**Edit:**

I did some more research and did some changes to my script:

```
find /volume2/Downloads/ -type f -mmin -60 | while IFS= read -r file; do
    if ffmpeg -i "${file}" | grep -q '(dut): Subtitle:'; then
        echo "matched"
    fi
done
```

Instead of "matched" it shows the ffmpeg output, but it's probably a step in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to redirect stderr to stdout.

```
find /volume2/Downloads/ -type f -mmin -60 | while IFS= read -r file; do
   if ffprobe -i "${file}" 2>&1 | grep -q '(dut): Subtitle:'; then
       echo "matched"
   fi
done
```

The question of using a pipe for your scenario has been discussed in [unix stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3514/how-to-grep-standard-error-stream-stderr)